# How to write CRON job running every 5 min from 8:55 am to 2:30 PM and running MONDAY to FRIDAY

Tags: java

need an cron expression to run every 5 min from 8:55 am to 2:30 PM on weekdays, below one will start @ 8:55 am and ends @ 2 PM , but need to end @ 2:30 PM, not getting how to end @ 2:30

0 55/5 8-14 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec() perhaps...